# Need to get a copy of a Sharepoint list from 2 days ago? Is this possible?

Tags: sharepoint

I had a On-premise Sharepoint Workflow completely delete data from a Sharepoint list 2 days ago.   I need a way to get back at that data.

Versioning is not turned on.  So I don't have an option to get back to it that way.

1. Can I get the admin to restore the list as a different name so I can manually pull the data?  If so, how is that done?
2. Can the admin restore the site under a different name so I can manually pull the data?  If so, how is that done?

Is either one of these possible?

I tried looking around sharepoint to see what option I have.  I don't see any.

Comment: What did your admin say when you asked?

Comment: They said this is not possible.  I find it hard to believe that such an enterprise software at a global financial company does not have a way to restore some data on a Sharepoint list.  :-)

Comment: Then you already know the answer to both questions is "no", so why are you here?

Comment: Because I am not a sharepoint expert and I don't trust the "experts" in the offshore group that support our Sharepoint.   They told me it wasn't possible.   I told them we are one of the largest financial companies in the world and they can't get some data a few days ago?   Finally I just told them I didn't believe them and that its impossible that we pay for this product and have no way to get back to older data.    After pushing they said they have backups and they would bring up the backup on a temporary site long enough for me to pull the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes this is possible to get at older list data as long as there is backups.   I convinced the admins to get the backups and bring up a temporary site long enough that I could pull the data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).